# expect: RSA key generation using expect script is not working

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am trying to generate SSH Keys using ssh-keygen command using expect script, but it seems to be not working (it is unable to create new keys or overwrite if keys are already present) i am unable to figure out the problem in this.

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-keygen
expect { -re "Enter file in which to save the key.*:\s?" {send "\n\r"; exp_continue}
         -re "Overwrite.*\?\s?" {send "y\r"; exp_continue}
         -re "Enter passphrase.*:\s?" {send "\n\r"; exp_continue}
         -re ".*#\s?" { puts "matched propmt"}
}
```

output from the script execution:

```
./ssh-key-gen.sh
spawn ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): [root@localhost scripts]#
```

Comment: Expect comes packaged with an `autoexpect` binary. Run it, then at the resultant prompt run your target command to completion. Once complete, type `exit`. A `script.exp` file will have been produced containing a complete expect script. I find this a great tool to troubleshoot these kinds of problems.

Comment: Have you tried turning on Expect's debugging mode?

Comment: i want to handle condition of checking if  i get the prompt to overwrite the keys or to continue as in when executing for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `send "\n\r"` in response to "Enter file in which to save the key". The \n accepts the default file name, then the \r is applied on the "Overwrite (y/n)?" prompt. An empty response to that question is interpreted as "no", so the command terminates. Get rid of that \n and it works.

But isn't it easier to just do:

```
set file [file normalize ~/.ssh/id_rsa]
file delete $file
exec ssh-keygen -f $file -N {}
```

That can be done in plain Tcl, no need for expect.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-keygen
expect { debug 1
         -re "Enter file in which to save the key.*:\s?" {send "\r"; exp_continue}
         -re "Overwrite.*\?\s?" {send "y\r"; exp_continue}
         -re "Enter passphrase.*:\s?" {send "\r"; exp_continue}
         -re ".*#\s?" { puts "matched propmt"}
}

Comment: I tried it myself before posting and the change I suggested worked for me. Other than that, I can only suggest to put `exp_internal 1` at the top of your script.

Comment: thank you, problem was i had the "-re" statement in the same line as the expect block begins  which was not matching the pattern, after moving the  regexp to the next line, it is working fine.